# Regex Pattern Within Case Class Pattern Using Scala

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching, case-class

This has gotta be something stupid, but I'm wondering if someone can help me out here. The following regex pattern match within a case class match is not working as I would expect. Can someone provide some insight?  Thanks.

```
object Confused {

  case class MyCaseClass(s: String)

  val WS = """\s*""".r

  def matcher(myCaseClass: MyCaseClass) = myCaseClass match {
    case MyCaseClass(WS(_)) => println("Found WS")
    case MyCaseClass(s) => println(s"Found >>$s<<")
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val ws = " "

    matcher(MyCaseClass(ws))
  }
}
```

I would expect the the first case in the pattern match to be the one that matches, but it is not.

This prints

> Found >> <<

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be:

```
val WS = """(\s*)""".r
```

For your question, you want to match a pattern of spaces, In ***Scala***,

> A regular expression is used to determine whether a string matches a
>   pattern and, if it does, to extract or transform the parts that match.

for extracting match parts we need to use `group` to pattern a string. It means that we need to use `parentheses` to around our pattern string.

Example:

```
val date = """(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)""".r
"2004-01-20" match {
  case date(year, month, day) => s"$year was a good year for PLs."
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @NathanOliver, Thanks, I have added details for explaining.